# Function NOW() on Qt

Tags: mysql, qt

I'm trying to implement this query with Qt:

```
mysqlpp::Query query = acdb.query();
query << "INSERT INTO jobs (jobType, creationDate, reelType)     
VALUES('ARCHIVE', NOW(), '" + reelType + "')";
```

where `NOW()` returns the current date and time.

This my code on Qt:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO jobs (jobType, creationDate, reelType) VALUES ('ARCHIVE', 
'NOW()', '" + reelType + "')");
```

here NOW returns 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Is there a similar function?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, but why the single quotes around the 'NOW()' in your Qt version? (I might be clueless, but it just struck me as odd :) )

Comment: I thought that as I loaded the QMYSQL drivers, the function NOW() work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert the string value `'NOW()'` into the datetime field, hence resulting in an invalid value:

```
"INSERT INTO jobs (jobType, creationDate, reelType) VALUES ('ARCHIVE', 
'NOW()', '" + reelType + "')");
```

Replace it with:

```
"INSERT INTO jobs (jobType, creationDate, reelType) VALUES ('ARCHIVE', 
NOW(), '" + reelType + "')");
```

Btw. `NOW()` is a pure SQL function. It doesn't matter which platform or framework you use to send the query, it is entirely evaluated by the SQL server.